# R split string to columns using string as column name and use any numbers as values in those columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = data.frame(id = 1:4, desc=c("httpmethod=put&hobbies=22.33&utiliites=50.00&home=950.00&entertainment=40.00&redirecturl=&stamp=5%0D%0A++++", "httpmethod=put&hobbies=&utiliites=&home=600.00&entertainment=25.57&redirecturl=&stamp=5%0D%0A++++", "httpmethod=put&hobbies=0.00&utiliites=&home=1127.53&entertainment=50.00&redirecturl=&stamp=5%0D%0A++++", "httpmethod=put&hobbies=&utiliites=&home=&entertainment=&redirecturl=&stamp=5%0D%0A++++"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Which gives:

| id | desc |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | httpmethod=put&hobbies=22.33&utiliites=50.00&home=950.00&entertainment=40.00&redirecturl=&stamp=5%0D%0A++++ |
| 2 | httpmethod=put&hobbies=&utiliites=&home=600.00&entertainment=25.57&redirecturl=&stamp=5%0D%0A++++ |
| 3 | httpmethod=put&hobbies=0.00&utiliites=&home=1127.53&entertainment=50.00&redirecturl=&stamp=5%0D%0A++++ |
| 4 | httpmethod=put&hobbies=&utiliites=&home=&entertainment=&redirecturl=&stamp=5%0D%0A++++ |

I'd like:

| id | hobbies | utilities | home | entertainment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22.33 | 50.00 | 950.00 | 40.00 |
| 2 | NA | NA | 600.00 | 25.57 |
| 3 | 0.00 | NA | 1127.53 | 50.00 |
| 4 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

I have looked at lots of different things but can't seem to bring it all together.  The code I have at the moment is as below, but I'm thinking there must be a more simple/eloquent way (e.g. get the column names from the string).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  separate(desc, c("http","hob", "utl", "hom", "ent", "redirect", "stamp"), sep = "&") %>% 
  mutate(hobbies = str_extract(hob, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")) %>%
  mutate(utilities = str_extract(utl, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")) %>%
  mutate(home = str_extract(hom, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")) %>%
  mutate(entertainment = str_extract(ent, "\\d+\\.*\\d*")) %>%
  select(-c("http","redirect", "stamp"))
```

I am quite new to R so some explanation of the steps would be good.  I did get to the point where I split them but ended up with a list and didn't know what to do to get the values out of the list.

Thanks

Comment: In the third row shouldn't be `hobbies=0.00` instead of `hobbies0.00=`?

Comment: Yes, typo, happened as I noticed when typing question I didn't have 0.00, so wanted to highlight I wanted 0.00 and not NA, corrected now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ignore warnings in this

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  separate_rows(desc, sep = '&') %>%
  separate(desc, into = c('n', 'v'), sep = '=') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = v, values_fn = as.numeric) 

#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#>      id httpmethod hobbies utiliites  home entertainment redirecturl stamp
#>   <int>      <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1         NA    22.3        50  950           40            NA    NA
#> 2     2         NA    NA          NA  600           25.6          NA    NA
#> 3     3         NA     0          NA 1128.          50            NA    NA
#> 4     4         NA    NA          NA   NA           NA            NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is a more general use case.  The other answer was specific to the question posted.  I also like how this answer doesn't rely on regex, and so easier, for me, to understand

Comment: Glad that it helped @purplealpha :)

Answer (score 3):

Once corrected third line `hobbies0.00=` as commented above,

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    separate(col = desc, into = c("http", "hobbies", "utiliites", "home", "entertainment", "redirecturl", "stamp"), sep = "&[a-z]+[0\\.]*=") %>% 
    select(-http, -redirecturl, -stamp)
  id hobbies utiliites    home entertainment
1  1   22.33     50.00  950.00         40.00
2  2                    600.00         25.57
3  3    0.00           1127.53         50.00
4  4
```

**Update**

A couple of modifications. One thanks to Shawn Brar comment, let's `as.numeric` all. The second one, to avoid specify the `into` vector (but having to remove some weird column):

```r
df1 %>% 
    separate(col = desc, into = strsplit(df1$desc[1], split = "=.*?&")[[1]], sep = "&[a-z]+=") %>% 
    select(-httpmethod, -redirecturl, -`stamp=5%0D%0A++++`) %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))

  id hobbies utiliites    home entertainment
1  1   22.33        50  950.00         40.00
2  2      NA        NA  600.00         25.57
3  3    0.00        NA 1127.53         50.00
4  4      NA        NA      NA            NA
```

Comment: You can use add `%>% mutate_all(as.numeric)` so that the column classes change to `numeric` and then you'll get the empty values as `NA`.

Comment: Thanks @iago, the updated part is exactly what I was looking for where it uses the string to get the names.  It's always the regular expressions that get me :) Also I've noticed there is an argument in separate `separate(..., convert = TRUE)`, that converts the new columns to numeric.

Comment: @purplealpha I updated again since I had written `[0\\.]*` in regular expressions only thinking in `hobbies0.00=` which was already solved, so it is not necessary.